# I can't install a .deb package

Tags: package-management, dpkg

After I input

```
sudo dpkg -i linuxqq_2.0.0-b1-1024_amd64.deb
```

It shows:

```
Preparing to unpack linuxqq_2.0.0-b1-1024_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linuxqq (2.0.0-b1) over (2.0.0-b1) ...
Setting up linuxqq (2.0.0-b1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
```

Do I need to mime-support dependency? But I don't know how to install it.

Comment: No, this is not an error. In fact `mime-support` is already installed, otherwise there were not triggers to process.

Comment: This .deb package does not seem to content all required inforamtion. You may unpacked it yourself (by use of midnight commander, e.g.), and take out the executable files and place them to the required path. I do not know if it could cause you can run safely the `qq` program. You can probe it.